# Passport.js authentication Failure

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I tried to write a username/password authentication server based on this project:

https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo.git

However I always receive a "Can\'t set headers after they are sent." error.

I don't want to use any login session so I removed all the code related to that.

Here is my code:

In app.js

```
......

// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./libs/auth/init');
initPassport(passport);

var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
app.use('/api', routes);

......
```

In ./libs/auth/init.js:

```
var signin = require('./signin');
var createuser = require('./createuser');
var User = require('../../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
    signin(passport);
    createuser(passport);
};
```

The signin.js:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use('signin', new LocalStrategy({
                passReqToCallback : true
            },
            function(req, username, password, done) {
                // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
                User.findOne({'username' : username},
                    function(err, user) {
                        // In case of any error, return using the done method
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                        // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                        if (!user) {
                            console.log('User Not Found with username ' + username);
                            return done(null, false);
                        }
                        // User exists but wrong password, log the error
                        if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                            console.log('Invalid Password');
                            return done(null, false); // redirect back to login page
                        }
                        // User and password both match, return user from done method
                        // which will be treated like success
                        return done(null, user);
                    }
                );

            })
    );

    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }
};
```

,which is almost the same as the original project

Also the createuser.js is almost the same as the original project:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use('createuser', new LocalStrategy({
                passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            function(req, username, password, done) {
                var findOrCreateUser = function() {
                    // find a user in Mongo with provided username
                    User.findOne({'username' : username}, function(err, user) {
                        // In case of any error, return using the done method
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error in SignUp: ' + err);
                            return done(err);
                        }
                        // already exists
                        if (user) {
                            console.log('User already exists with username: ' + username);
                            return done(null, false);
                        } else {
                            // if there is no user with that email
                            // create the user
                            var newUser = new User();
                            // set the user's local credentials
                            newUser.username = username;
                            newUser.password = createHash(password);
                            // save the user
                            newUser.save(function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
                                    throw err;
                                }
                                console.log('User Registration successful');
                                return done(null, newUser);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                };
                // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
                // in the next tick of the event loop
                process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
            })
    );

    // Generates hash using bCrypt
    var createHash = function(password){
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    }
};
```

The model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{
    id: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

The ./routes/index.js is very different from the origin file. Because I am trying to implement user authentication apis, I want to send back some json data after user authentication instead of redirecting them to another url.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport) {
    router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('signin', {session : false},
        function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    message: "Internal Server Error!"
                })
            } else if (!user) {
                res.json({
                    message: "No Such User!"
                })
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        message: "Login Failure!"
                    })
                }
                res.json({
                    message: "Login Success!"
                })
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });

    router.post('/createuser', function(req, res, next) {
       passport.authenticate('createuser', {session : false},
       function(err, user, info) {
           if (err) {
               res.json({
                   message: "Internal Server Error!"
               })
           } else if (!user) {
               res.json({
                   message: "User Creation failure!"
               })
           }
           res.json({
               message: "Create User Success!"
           })
       })(req, res, next);
    });

    return router;
};
```

However this seems doesn't work well. For the signin api I receive that error message every time I make a request from curl, like:

```
 curl --data "username=2232&password=223" http://localhost:3000/api/signin
```

For the createuser api only when create user succeeds it doesn't crash. Otherwise I will still receive that error message.

BTW, I am not sure what the done method is doing under the hood. Anyone can give me some details?

---

I would be appreciated if anyone can answer this question as well:
This is the first time I tried to design an web api. What I am trying to do seems odd to me: The server receives a username and password, then it looks it up in the database, if it finds it then just tell the client "hey I found you!". Then no side effect occurs.

I don't think this is the right way how authentication api works. I would expect the server generate some kind of access key together with an expiration time. However I don't find passport.js has the capacity to do that. Am I using the wrong lib to do the authentication api with node.js?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file you need to use `return` when sending the response, because just calling the `res.json` method the execution of function is not stopped and the server tries to send two responses, that's what the error says you.

You should modify your code:

```
router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('signin', {session : false},
    function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({
                message: "Internal Server Error!"
            })
        } else if (!user) {
            return res.json({
                message: "No Such User!"
            })
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    message: "Login Failure!"
                })
            }
            return res.json({
                message: "Login Success!"
            })
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/createuser', function(req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate('createuser', {session : false},
   function(err, user, info) {
       if (err) {
           return res.json({
               message: "Internal Server Error!"
           })
       } else if (!user) {
           return res.json({
               message: "User Creation failure!"
           })
       }
       return res.json({
           message: "Create User Success!"
       })
   })(req, res, next);
});
```